# Stress-ng - Overload Memory

Tags: unix, stress-testing, stress-ng

I want to test the systems reaction to a process that wants to consume more memory than there is available. 
I run stress-ng with the following command (on a 6G RAM machine): 
`stress-ng --vm-bytes 8G  --vm-keep -m 1 --aggressive`
but I get this error:
`stress-ng: error: [5035] stress-ng-vm: gave up trying to mmap, no available memory`
Is it possible to force the program to ignore its own secure mechanism ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add this parameter `--vm 4`
I was having the same problem and it is gone after that.

Comment: if it still fails, try this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/580467/235896 `sudo sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=0` (but here it was already 0 and would not make a difference)

Comment: @JeremyCaney well, actually as I couldn't verify that the link content work on my machine, I think it is better for it to be just a comment :)